# Does Salesforce2Salesforce work with Person Accounts?

Tags: person-accounts, salesforce2salesforce

Has anyone successfully shared Person Accounts to another Salesforce org using Salesforce to Salesforce? Does it work well? If there are any gotchas, please tell me.

In both orgs, the data will be stored in person accounts.
When I want to filter on which person accounts get shared, based on some field values and record type, I assume I have to do it in apex (see https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practices_for_Salesforce_to_Salesforce#Best_Practice:_Automatically_share_new_accounts). Can I just share the account, or do I have to share both the account and the contact?